# how to link my blog to the android app that i create?

Tags: java, android

I have created the application ,in one of the buttons.I need to display the  link of the blog,so that the user can see my blog when he clicks on it.thanks!

Comment: Welcome! What did you try and where is your code? Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Add that to the buttons click handler to launch example.com in the web browser